# Why does DOMPDF does not style a paragraph with Word Wrap?

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to word-wrap a text with no spaces in a PDF and when I tried to download it. It's not working but when I see it in view it's working fine. What would be the workaround for this??

This is the View 
[image: View]

[image: In PDF]

And the next one is the PDF after download.

Comment: Which dompdf version you are using?

Comment: @Sehdev `"name": "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf",

  "version": "v0.8.5",`